# redirect all subdomains to main domain (SSL) with subdomain as query parameter using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Trying to do all of the following in the `.htaccess` file in the most elegant way:

- redirect all non-SSL to SSL
- redirect www to non-www
- redirect all other subdomains to main domain with query string parameter as the
  subdomain. Ignore any other info in the URL (302 redirect). For example: `http(s)://subdomain.example.com(/or/any/other/folder/or_file.html)` -> `https://example.com/results.php?q=subdomain`
- redirect all main domain 404 to main domain with query string using only
  the first folder or filename as the parameter. for example: `http(s)://example.com/does/not/exist/file.html` -> `https://example.com/results.php?q=does`

Here is what I have so far and everything works except for the subdomain redirect and the SSL redirect doesn't always work with non-SSL URLs. Not sure about the order of things or if there is a way to combine some of these.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
# this rewrites all non-SSL www to main domain (SSL)
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect all 404 to query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? /results.php?q=$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

IMPORTANT: everything needs to be a redirect and not a rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and the SSL redirect doesn't always work with non-SSL URLs.

Because you don't have a specific non-SSL (HTTP) to SSL (HTTPS) redirect, only a www to non-www redirect that also redirects to HTTPS.

You can do it like this:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect all 404 (for www or main domain) to query string + main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) https://%1/results.php?q=$1 [R=302,L]

# Redirect www to main domain (+ HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect subdomains to main domain and query string
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.(example\.com)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2/results.php?q=%1 [R=302,L]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (remaining URLs) - must already be at main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I've arranged/constructed the rules in order to minimise the number of possible redirects. There is only ever at most 1 redirect.

The redirect from HTTP to HTTPS (the last rule) in which we are testing against the `HTTPS` server variable assumes the SSL cert is installed on your application server and you have a relatively standard implementation.

You could make the rules entirely generic and remove the reliance on `example.com` (to determine what is a subdomain etc) by assuming the domain is always of the form `<domain>.<tld>` for instance (or of a known subset of TLDs perhaps).

Just an observation... seems a little odd that you would redirect both subdomains and the first path segment of non-existent files/directories to the same URL format?

Comment: The code above returns the error "The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected."

Comment: @Dagon There was a typo... "`RewriteCodn`" (in the 3rd rule) should be `RewriteCond` (now corrected). What was the response code?